# I'm trying to import a `.txt file` into a workbook from another workbook but doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

Let's say i'm working on workbook A and workbook A produce a `.txt file`.
I also have workbook B witch contain a table that is ready to receive data from a `.txt file`.
i want to import the `.txt file`produce by workbook A into workbook B and i want to do so with workbook A
here's my code:

```
Sub result_template()

Dim FL As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim restemplate As Object

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)   '
            .Title = "Select the log file"                 'Open the file explorer
            .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"         'for you to select
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
            .AllowMultiSelect = False                          'to format
            .Show

            If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then Sheets(5).Cells(36, 16).Value = .SelectedItems(1)

        End With

        With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)   '
            .Title = "Select the result template"              'Open the file explorer
            .InitialFileName = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"         'for you to select
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails            'the file you want
            .AllowMultiSelect = False                          'to format
            .Show

            If Not .SelectedItems(1) = vbNullString Then FL = .SelectedItems(1)
            Set restemplate = wb.OpenText(FL, 3, xlDelimited, True, True)

        'Code to copy the contents of the .txt file to your table

            ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True filename:="result" & Date


        End With

End Sub
```

I have a syntaxe error on `ActiveWorkbook.Close`
and have Object variable not set error on `Set restemplate = wb.OpenText(FL, 3, xlDelimited, True, True)`

what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing a comma before `filename:=`, you'll probably need to `Format` the date instead of just `& Date`. Then, `Workbooks.OpenText` doesn't return anything so you can't do `Set restemplate = ...`

Comment: where can i find more info on how to make Workbooks.OpenText return something? there's something i don't understand here but don't know what!

Comment: It doesn't return anything and never will - this is a case where you need to work with `ActiveWorkbook` immediately after `Workbooks.OpenText`.